# Query custom dimensions Google analytics API

Tags: python, google-analytics

I would like to generate a custom report through Python, using HelloAnalytics API IV. It worked well, until I tried to add a custom dimension to the other dimensions.
 I'm struggling to find the naming convention to call a custom dimension (dimension2) in this code :

```
def get_report(analytics):
return analytics.reports().batchGet(
  body={
    'reportRequests': [
    {
      'viewId': VIEW_ID,
      'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '7daysAgo', 'endDate': 'today'}],
      'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'},{'expression':'ga:bounces'},{'expression':'ga:CTR'}],
      'dimensions': [{'name':'ga:campaign'},{'name':'ga:sourceMedium'},{'name':'ga:dimension2'}]
    }]
  }
).execute()
```

I keep getting the error: "returned "Unknown dimension(s): ga:dimension2">"

Should I define the dimension in some variable before this part of code ? 
Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you define the dimension in the Google Analytics property that contains the view you're querying?

Comment: You're right... I had not filled the right view ID. Thanks !